# Rendering different view classes based on the value of a string

Tags: javascript

Here I'm instantiating different classes based on the value of a `type` property. This `type` property will determine what view is rendered and displayed on screen to the user.

As you can see there's a lot of repetition here. The main problem I'd like to eliminate is all those `else if`s.

```
onShow: function() {
    var type = this.model.get('type').toLowerCase();

    if (type === 'face') {
        this.regionItems.show(new FaceDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    } else if (type === 'voice') {
        this.regionItems.show(new VoiceDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    } else if (type === 'text-prompted') {
        this.regionItems.show(new VoiceDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));

    } else if (type === 'face-password (text)') {
        this.regionItems.show(new PinDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));

    } else if (type === 'pin') {
        this.regionItems.show(new PinDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    }  else if (type === 'live voice') {
        this.regionItems.show(new VoiceLiveness({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    } else if (type === 'voice-face (image)') {
        this.regionItems.show(new FaceDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    } else if (type === 'voice-face (audio)') {
        this.regionItems.show(new VoiceDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    } else if (type === 'gps') {
        this.regionItems.show(new GPSDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));

    } else if (type === 'face-password (image)') {
        this.regionItems.show(new FaceDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    } else if (type === 'voice-face (challenge audio)') {
        this.regionItems.show(new VoiceLiveness({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    } else if (type === 'fingerprint') {
        this.regionItems.show(new FingerDetail({
            model               : this.model,
            authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
            collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
        }));
    }
}
```

I intend to extract

```
{
    model               : this.model,
    authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
    collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
}
```

to the top of the method as an `options` variable and then pass it to the constructor when I instantiate each view (`FaceDetail`, `VoiceDetail`, etc.)

After this I'm still left with all those `else if`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The obvious answer is to introduce a map:

```
var typeToConstructor = {
    'face' : FaceDetail,
    'voice' : VoiceDetail,
    // ...
}
```

Then you can simply look up your constructor function:

```
onShow: function() {
    var type = this.model.get('type').toLowerCase();
    var constructor = typeToConstructor[type];
    if (typeof constructor !== 'function') {
        // Unknown type... do something
    }

    // execute the constructor.
    this.regionItems.show(new constructor({
        model               : this.model,
        authRequestModel    : this.authRequestModel,
        collection          : this.model.attemptItemsDataCollection
    });
}
```

Comment: I was considering this but there is a slightly awkward situation where multiple types map to the same class. e.g. both `voice` and `text-prompted` map to the `VoiceDetail` class. I know that this doesn't rule out the "mapping" object at all but I thought it would be good if there was a way to map each class to multiple types, without repeating the class name....if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, it's one of those times where you have to put the mapping in somewhere and it's usually going to be horrible looking. Just realised I wrote "obvious" when I really meant "superficial".

Comment: To be fair, a mapping object is pretty much the "obvious" answer

Comment: For what it's worth, it's completely fine and proper to have the same value appear multiple times in a map.